# Como preencher gráficos de coluna com hachuras usando ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Gostaria de apresentar gráficos de colunas, utilizando o `ggplot2`, porém gostaria que o preenchimento deles fossem com hachuras. Pois facilita o entendimento em caso de fotocópia em preto e branco!

[image: Exemplo de preenchimento com hachuras (linhas pontilhadas)]

Usando a data base `cars` e o comando abaixo como exemplo, como ficaria?

```
library(ggplot2)
data(cars)
g <- ggplot(mpg, aes(class))
g + geom_bar()
```

Comment: O que seria um preenchimento com hachuras?

Answer (score 8):

Utilize o pacote `ggtextures`, disponível [neste link](https://github.com/clauswilke/ggtextures).

```
devtools::install_github("clauswilke/ggtextures")
library(ggplot2)
library(ggtextures)

images = c(
  compact = "http://www.hypergridbusiness.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/rocks2-256.jpg",
  midsize = "http://www.hypergridbusiness.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/stone2-256.jpg",
  suv = "http://www.hypergridbusiness.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/siding1-256.jpg",
  `2seater` = "http://www.hypergridbusiness.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/mulch1-256.jpg",
  minivan = "http://www.hypergridbusiness.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/rocks1-256.jpg",
  pickup = "http://www.hypergridbusiness.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/wood3-256.jpg",
  subcompact = "http://www.hypergridbusiness.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/concrete1-256.jpg"
)

ggplot(mpg, aes(class, image = class)) +
  geom_textured_bar() +
  scale_image_manual(values = images) +
  labs(x="Tipo de Carro", y="Frequência", image="Tipo de Carro")
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agora é só escolher imagens com as texturas ou hachuras que melhor te atendam.

Comment: Agradeço pela boa vontade, porém não consegui instalar o pacote!!! mesmo usando suas instruções: devtools::install_github("clauswilke/ggtextures")

Comment: 1) Instale o pacote `devtools` primeiro: `install.packages("devtools")` 2) Rode novamente o comando que te passei.